# Hadoop Map output IOException when emitting subclass of a class defined in Configuration as an ouput

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, subclass, ioexception

I have 3 simple classes:

```
public abstract class Container implements WritableComparable<Container> {} //empty
public class WeightedEdge extends Container { ... }
public class NodeWeightContainer extends Container { ... }
```

The Map phase was configured as such

```
JobConf createGraphPConf = new JobConf(new Configuration());
Job job = new Job(createGraphPConf);
...
createGraphPConf.setMapOutputValueClass(Container.class);
```

However I am receiving this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.hadoop.test.data.util.Container, recieved org.hadoop.test.data.WeightedEdge
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1018)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$OldOutputCollector.collect(MapTask.java:591)
at org.hadoop.test.map.CreateGPMap.map(CreateGPMap.java:33)
at org.hadoop.test.map.CreateGPMap.map(CreateGPMap.java:19)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:435)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:371)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:210)
```

Why I can't return a subclass of a class that was defined in the configuration? Is there a way around it? The problem is that my Map phase has to emit two distinct object types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not return a subclass of a class that was defined in the configuration because Hadoop explicitly checks class type specified in `setMapOutputValueClass` and the type it receives from Mappers.

It does so because it needs to serialize/deserialize objects you emit from mappers. When it performs deserialization it creates new object of type that is specified in  `setMapOutputValueClass` call and then uses methods of WriteableComparable interface to fill newly created object with data.

To be able to emit different object types you may define container non-abstract class and place actual object and its type identifier inside

```
    public enum ELEM_TYPE { WE, WECONTAINER }

    public class Container implements WritableComparable<Container>
    {
        ELEM_TYPE  type; //actual element type -
                         // WeightedEdge  or NodeWeightContainer 
        object value;

        //WritableComparable implementation
        // that casts value to the appropriate type
    } 
    public class WeightedEdge { ... }
    public class NodeWeightContainer { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem today. There is a `Writable` class `org.apache.hadoop.io.GenericWritable` which can be used to address this problem. You need to extend the class and implement an abstract method:

```
public class Container extends GenericWritable {

    private static Class[] CLASSES = {
           WeightedEdge.class, 
           NodeWeightContainer.class,
    };

    protected Class[] getTypes() {
       return CLASSES;
    }

}

public class WeightedEdge implemets Writable {...}
public class NodeWeightContainer implements Writable {...}
```

Now you can use the class `Container` as the output value type of your mapper.

Important: Your actual map output classes (`WeightedEdge` and `NodeWeightContainer`) must implement the `Writable` interface.